# How to get the Microsoft Template folder using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

How to get following sample folder path using c#?

> `C:\Users\User-Name-A1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`

This can be different on different computers, in this case how to do this?

Can somebody help me sample code?

Comment: It's application specific, what you may get is path to AppData (why you force to "Roaming"?) with [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx) (see [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx)) then build path from that.

Comment: Are you not mistake? Maybe you mean:
C:\Users\User-Name-A1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates

Comment: Hi Guys, using this Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)); can I get what I am asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates)
```

Comment: I tried like this but error..... string av = Environment.GetFolderPath("Templates").ToString();   error:The best overloaded method match for 'System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder)' has some invalid arguments & cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Environment.SpecialFolder

Comment: Yes, I got like this..... string av = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates).ToString();